# How can vscode print (or paste) all open file paths to a new file in the editor?

Tags: macros, visual-studio-code

In vscode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> displays open files, but how can vscode print (or paste) the same 'all open file paths' to a new file in the editor?

Comment: in an extension you can enumerate all open files and add there filenames to the current editor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have this setting set to a high enough number to show all your open files:

> Editor > Open Editors: Visible

then you can select all the files from the `Open Editors` viewlet (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for instance) in the Explorer, right-click and choose `Copy Path` or `Copy Relative Path` and then paste it yourself into a new file.  Demo:

[image: openfile paths]

---

For how to automatically send selected (modify the variable for clipboard text) to a new file see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57612004/836330.  I suppose the whole thing might be made into a macro.

Here is the macro.  Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your settings.json:

```
 "multiCommand.commands": [

    {
      "command": "multiCommand.getOpenFilePaths",

      "sequence": [
        "workbench.files.action.focusOpenEditorsView",
        "list.selectAll",
        "copyFilePath",               // full paths
         // "copyRelativeFilePath",   // relative paths
        "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",

        // prompt for save immediately?
        // "workbench.action.files.saveAs",
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and some keybinding to trigger that macro:

```
{
  "key": "alt+o",         // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.getOpenFilePaths" },
},
```

The `Open Editors` viewlet can be collapsed if you wish when you trigger the macro and it still works.  Demo:

[image: get open file paths macro]

Comment: Was always thinking of copying all file paths of all tabs. Great tip!

Answer (score 0):

[Adding another answer because the first was long and very different.]

Here is a simpler way to print a list of the currently open files to a newly created file.  It does **not** require that the `Open Editors` view be visible.  It uses newer extension api to access the tabs currently open.

It uses an extension (I wrote), [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).  In this extension, you can use the vscode extension api.  Make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`) (it could also be made into a command accessible from the Command Palette):

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
   
    "replace": [
      "$${",
      
      "let str = '';",
      "const groups = vscode.window.tabGroups.all;",  // if multiple editor groups
      "groups.map((group, index) => {",
        "str += 'Group ' + (index+1) + '\\n';", 
        "group.tabs.map(tab => {",
          "if (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText) str += '\\t' + tab.input.uri.fsPath + '\\n';",

          // the above prints the full path, use below if you only want the tab file label only
          // "str += tab.label + '\\n';",

        "});",
        "str += '\\n';",
      "});",
      "vscode.env.clipboard.writeText( str );",
      "return '';",   

      "}$$"
    ],
    
    // open a new file and paste to it
    "postCommands": ["workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile", "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"]
  },
}
```

[image: list open files in a new file]

To open a save file dialog use this `"postCommands"` entry.

```
    "postCommands": [
      "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile",
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
      "workbench.action.files.save"
    ]
```