# Visual studio code - create a macro that copies content over files

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, macros, refactoring

I'm looking into creating something like a macro for localization of strings. Until now, I have only find that (maybe) a custom *Code Action* might be what I need.

After I select some code, let's call it `selection`, I want the to:

1. Ask me for a `name`
2. Write to another file: `name = selection`
3. Write in current file:    `(some_fixed_code)name(some_other_fixed_code)`

Is there any way to create that macro, for it lo launch with a left click option or a keyboard shortcut?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: easiest is to write your own extension for that, or you can try to use [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions), if needed create a request to add the possibility to use the current selection

Comment: Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57612004/836330

Comment: @rioV8 I'm using My Code Actions, but the php action I added doesn't show, I opened an issue in your GitHub repository